# How to create a udev rules?

Tags: systemd, udev

I am trying to create a simple udev rule, for the device below, Sony Computer Entertainment Inc BD Remote Control, but it does not work, I have read several tutorials, some documentation and other doubt posts like this one, in no case can I make it work.

I just do not know if it's an error in device attributes, distrubution that does not support udev rules or any other error.

"sudo reboot" is for testing purposes only.

I'm using Linux Mint.

> Linux Mint Linux HP 4.15.0-20-generic # 21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24
>   06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU / Linux

Here's one of several tests I've done:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", SUBSYSTEMS=="input",
ATTR{phys}=="00:19:86:00:15:36", RUN+="sudo reboot"
```

---

```
Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:054C:0306.003A/input/input70/event15':
    KERNEL=="event15"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:054C:0306.003A/input/input70':
    KERNELS=="input70"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{name}=="Sony Computer Entertainment Inc BD Remote Control"
    ATTRS{phys}=="00:19:86:00:15:36"
    ATTRS{properties}=="0"
    ATTRS{uniq}=="00:06:f5:97:ab:94"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:054C:0306.003A':
    KERNELS=="0005:054C:0306.003A"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
    DRIVERS=="sony"
    ATTRS{country}=="21"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11':
    KERNELS=="hci0:11"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="bluetooth"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0':
    KERNELS=="hci0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="bluetooth"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="2-1.1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="btusb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1':
    KERNELS=="2-1.1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0112"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="22"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="21e8"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0a5c"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Broadcom Corp"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="BCM20702A0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{serial}=="001986001536"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="434"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1':
    KERNELS=="2-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0000"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0024"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="6"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="fixed"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="497"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2':
    KERNELS=="usb2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0415"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.15.0-20-generic ehci_hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="2"
    ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="187"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1d.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="ehci-pci"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0320"
    ATTRS{companion}==""
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1e26"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="23"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="0f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x04"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x1854"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x103c"
    ATTRS{uframe_periodic_max}=="100"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

---

Update: Using the command `sudo systemctl status udev.service` it seems that the rules are working, but not running script (`.sh`) or program (`/usr/bin/qbittorrent`) and referencing this error.

```
● systemd-udevd.service - udev Kernel Device Manager
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-03-06 12:21:22 -03; 8min ago
Docs: man:systemd-udevd.service(8)
      man:udev(7)
Main PID: 399 (systemd-udevd)
Status: "Processing with 16 children at max"
Tasks: 1
CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-udevd.service
        └─399 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd

mar 06 12:21:25 HP systemd-udevd[1939]: Process '/home/luiz/loop.sh' failed with exit code 1.
mar 06 12:21:26 HP systemd-udevd[2196]: Process '/home/luiz/loop.sh' failed with exit code 1. 
mar 06 12:21:26 HP systemd-udevd[2220]: Process '/home/luiz/loop.sh' failed with exit code 1. 
mar 06 12:21:31 HP systemd-udevd[2504]: Process '/home/luiz/loop.sh' failed with exit code 1.
mar 06 12:25:42 HP systemd-udevd[3225]: Process '/home/luiz/loop.sh' failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: In your test rule, you're tying the rule to an `input` subsystem device that is a child device of another `input` subsystem device, and then requiring an `ATTR{phys}`... but according to your `udevadm info` listing, the top block (`KERNEL=="event15"`) does not include a `phys` attribute at all. Since the attribute is not in the top-most block of `udevadm info`, it needs to be `ATTRS{phys}` instead.

Comment: Also, `qbittorrent` is a GUI program, and it would need at least the `DISPLAY` variable and a `~/.Xauthority` file (or a properly set `XAUTHORITY` variable to point to a `.Xauthority` file elsewhere) set properly in order to run... and unless you do something to change it, your script will be running as root. If you're logged in as `luiz`, then any old `/root/.Xauthority` file will be invalidated by the X server, and the udev rule running as root cannot insert `qbittorrent` into `luiz`'s X11 session, at least not without first stealing the X11 magic cookie.

Comment: Hello, 'qbittorrent' was just one of the tests, I tested it with 'reboot', 'sudo reboot', '/ usr / bin / xinput --disable 14' (to disable touchpad) and etc and all gave me the same result at the end I noticed that when running 'sudo systemctl status udev.service' it shows this error 'exit code 1'.

Comment: Hello, qbittorrent was just one of the tests, I tested it with 'reboot', 'sudo reboot', '/ usr / bin / xinput --disable 14' (to disable touchpad) and etc and all gave me the same result at the end I noticed that when running 'systemctl status udev.service' it shows this error 'exit code 1'.

Last tests:

`ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTR{name}=="Sony Computer Entertainment Inc BD Remote Control", RUN+="/usr/bin/qbittorrent"`

---------

`ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="event*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTR{idProduct}=="07a5", ATTR{idVendor}=="045e", RUN+="/home/luiz/loop.sh"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to create an udev rule in `/lib/udev/rules.d` with the format:

```
ACTION=="add", \
    SUBSYSTEM=="input", \
        ATTR{uniq}=="00:06:f5:97:ab:94" \
                RUN+="/bin/systemctl start --no-block ps3bdremote.service
```

Instead of running a script I run a service using the command `/bin/systemctl start --no-block` to this is the service, if I'm not mistaken this solution corrects timeout problems when running long-running scripts, but I didn't get to test it.

This is the service in `/etc/systemd/system/ps3bdremote.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=PS3 BD Remote Script.

[Service]
Type=simple
User=luiz
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/luiz/.Xauthority
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /media/luiz/HD/posinstall/repos/ps3bdremote/ps3bdremote.py -s

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

This part I believe is optional, if someone tries something similar, I used it because it allows to generate desktop notifications (use KDE), but it must be the same in other interfaces.

```
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/luiz/.Xauthority
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```